# Circular Image View stretched

Tags: java, android

I am using the following code for creating a circular image view within my project.

```
public class CircularImageView extends ImageView {
    // Border & Selector configuration variables
    private boolean hasBorder;
    private boolean hasSelector;
    private boolean isSelected;
    private int borderWidth;
    private int canvasSize;
    private int selectorStrokeWidth;

    // Objects used for the actual drawing
    private BitmapShader shader;
    private Bitmap image;
    private Paint paint;
    private Paint paintBorder;
    private Paint paintSelectorBorder;
    private ColorFilter selectorFilter;

    public CircularImageView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        this(context, attrs, R.attr.circularImageViewStyle);
    }

    public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes paint objects and sets desired attributes.
     *
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     * @param defStyle
     */
    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        // Initialize paint objects
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paintBorder = new Paint();
        paintBorder.setAntiAlias(true);
        paintSelectorBorder = new Paint();
        paintSelectorBorder.setAntiAlias(true);

        // load the styled attributes and set their properties
        TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CircularImageView, defStyle, 0);

        // Check if border and/or border is enabled
        hasBorder = attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.CircularImageView_border, false);
        hasSelector = attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.CircularImageView_selector, false);

        // Set border properties if enabled
        if(hasBorder) {
            int defaultBorderSize = (int) (2 * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
            setBorderWidth(attributes.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.styleable.CircularImageView_border_width, defaultBorderSize));
            setBorderColor(attributes.getColor(R.styleable.CircularImageView_border_color, Color.WHITE));
        }

        // Set selector properties if enabled
        if(hasSelector) {
            int defaultSelectorSize = (int) (2 * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
            setSelectorColor(attributes.getColor(
                R.styleable.CircularImageView_selector_color, Color.TRANSPARENT));
            setSelectorStrokeWidth(attributes.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.styleable.CircularImageView_selector_stroke_width, defaultSelectorSize));
            setSelectorStrokeColor(attributes.getColor(R.styleable.CircularImageView_selector_stroke_color, Color.BLUE));
        }

        // Add shadow if enabled
        if(attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.CircularImageView_shadow, false))
            addShadow();

        // We no longer need our attributes TypedArray, give it back to cache
        attributes.recycle();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the CircularImageView's border width in pixels.
     *
     * @param borderWidth
     */
    public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth) {
        this.borderWidth = borderWidth;
        this.requestLayout();
        this.invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the CircularImageView's basic border color.
     *
     * @param borderColor
     */
    public void setBorderColor(int borderColor) {
        if (paintBorder != null)
            paintBorder.setColor(borderColor);
        this.invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the color of the selector to be draw over the
     * CircularImageView. Be sure to provide some opacity.
     *
     * @param selectorColor
     */
    public void setSelectorColor(int selectorColor) {
        this.selectorFilter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(selectorColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        this.invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the stroke width to be drawn around the CircularImageView
     * during click events when the selector is enabled.
     *
     * @param selectorStrokeWidth
     */
    public void setSelectorStrokeWidth(int selectorStrokeWidth) {
        this.selectorStrokeWidth = selectorStrokeWidth;
        this.requestLayout();
        this.invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the stroke color to be drawn around the CircularImageView
     * during click events when the selector is enabled.
     *
     * @param selectorStrokeColor
     */
    public void setSelectorStrokeColor(int selectorStrokeColor) {
        if (paintSelectorBorder != null)
            paintSelectorBorder.setColor(selectorStrokeColor);
        this.invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a dark shadow to this CircularImageView.
     */
    public void addShadow() {
        setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paintBorder);
        paintBorder.setShadowLayer(4.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, Color.BLACK);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // Don't draw anything without an image
        if(image == null)
            return;

        // Nothing to draw (Empty bounds)
        if(image.getHeight() == 0 || image.getWidth() == 0)
            return;

        // Compare canvas sizes
        int oldCanvasSize = canvasSize;

        canvasSize = canvas.getWidth();
        if(canvas.getHeight() < canvasSize)
            canvasSize = canvas.getHeight();

        // Reinitialize shader, if necessary
        if(oldCanvasSize != canvasSize)
            refreshBitmapShader();

        // Apply shader to paint
        paint.setShader(shader);

        // Keep track of selectorStroke/border width
        int outerWidth = 0;

        // Get the exact X/Y axis of the view
        int center = canvasSize / 2;


        if(hasSelector && isSelected) { // Draw the selector stroke & apply the selector filter, if applicable
            outerWidth = selectorStrokeWidth;
            center = (canvasSize - (outerWidth * 2)) / 2;

            paint.setColorFilter(selectorFilter);
            canvas.drawCircle(center + outerWidth, center + outerWidth, ((canvasSize - (outerWidth * 2)) / 2) + outerWidth - 4.0f, paintSelectorBorder);
        }
        else if(hasBorder) { // If no selector was drawn, draw a border and clear the filter instead... if enabled
            outerWidth = borderWidth;
            center = (canvasSize - (outerWidth * 2)) / 2;

            paint.setColorFilter(null);
            canvas.drawCircle(center + outerWidth, center + outerWidth, ((canvasSize - (outerWidth * 2)) / 2) + outerWidth - 4.0f, paintBorder);
        }
        else // Clear the color filter if no selector nor border were drawn
            paint.setColorFilter(null);

        // Draw the circular image itself
        canvas.drawCircle(center + outerWidth, center + outerWidth, ((canvasSize - (outerWidth * 2)) / 2) - 4.0f, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Check for clickable state and do nothing if disabled
        if(!this.isClickable()) {
            this.isSelected = false;
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        // Set selected state based on Motion Event
        switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                this.isSelected = true;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                this.isSelected = false;
                break;
        }

        // Redraw image and return super type
        this.invalidate();
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public void invalidate(Rect dirty) {
        super.invalidate(dirty);
        image = drawableToBitmap(getDrawable());
        if(shader != null || canvasSize > 0)
            refreshBitmapShader();
    }

    public void invalidate(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.invalidate(l, t, r, b);
        image = drawableToBitmap(getDrawable());
        if(shader != null || canvasSize > 0)
            refreshBitmapShader();
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidate() {
        super.invalidate();
        image = drawableToBitmap(getDrawable());
        if(shader != null || canvasSize > 0)
            refreshBitmapShader();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width = measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    private int measureWidth(int measureSpec) {
        int result;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            // The parent has determined an exact size for the child.
            result = specSize;
        }
        else if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            // The child can be as large as it wants up to the specified size.
            result = specSize;
        }
        else {
            // The parent has not imposed any constraint on the child.
            result = canvasSize;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private int measureHeight(int measureSpecHeight) {
        int result = 0;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpecHeight);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpecHeight);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            // We were told how big to be
            result = specSize;
        } else if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            // The child can be as large as it wants up to the specified size.
            result = specSize;
        } else {
            // Measure the text (beware: ascent is a negative number)
            result = canvasSize;
        }

        return (result + 2);
    }

    /**
     * Convert a drawable object into a Bitmap
     *
     * @param drawable
     * @return
     */
    public Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
        if (drawable == null) { // Don't do anything without a proper drawable
            return null;
        }
        else if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) { // Use the getBitmap() method instead if BitmapDrawable
            return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        }

        // Create Bitmap object out of the drawable
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);

        return bitmap;
    }

    /**
     * Reinitializes the shader texture used to fill in
     * the Circle upon drawing.
     */
    public void refreshBitmapShader() {
        shader = new BitmapShader(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, canvasSize, canvasSize, false), Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether or not this view is currently
     * in its selected state.
     */
    public boolean isSelected() {
        return this.isSelected;
    }
}
```

The circle effect is created, but the problem is all my pictures are being narrowed, as in the picture is too big and it's trying to fit in the circular image view. Any possible solutions to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the size of the circular image view is fixed, the only way to avoid stretching the image is to crop it to the same aspect ratio as the image view, or else introduce margins on the top or sides.

Since you are already scaling the bitmap to the canvas size inside refreshBitmapShader(), that is a convenient place to crop it using [Bitmap.createBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20boolean)):

```
public void refreshBitmapShader() {        
    int left = 0; y = 0; w = image.getWidth(), h = image.getHeight(); 
    // decide whether we have to crop the sizes or the top and bottom:
    if(w > h)  // width is greater than height
    {
        x = (w - h) >> 1;   // crop sides, half on each side
        w = h;
    }
    else
    {
        y = (h - w) >> 1;   // crop top and bottom
        h = w;
    }
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    float scale = (float)canvasSize / (float)w;
    m.preScale(scale, scale);   // scale to canvas size
    shader = new BitmapShader(Bitmap.createBitmap(image, x, y, w, h, m, false), Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
}
```

Comment: The size of the circular image view is fixed indeed and cropping seems like it is the only solution in here and your solution does the trick for me. Thanks a lot!

The problem with this solution is that the cropping will be noticeable when the picture is a close up. How does though Facebook, Tinder or WhatsApp manage to have the same effect without loosing parts of the picture due to cropping?

Comment: I don't know how Facebook etc does it. Perhaps they only crop it half as much, so that it's only a little bit cropped and a little bit stretched, and neither looks too bad. Also FB might be using face recognition to chose the crop area more intelligently. Just speculating.